# event "on paste" not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

I have this code for event paste to manage when something is pasted to an input.

```
$(document).on('paste','.paste',function () {
    alert('something pasted');
});
```

Input is defined on HTML like this

```
<INPUT name='textinput' class='paste' type='text'>
```

I've been trying with the debugguer and event handler is not called. I use class and not ID because I have many inputs to manage. Also my inputs are appended after page load. For this reason I use `$(document).on` method. Any ideas or suggestions? What's wrong with this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: your code works for me. (chrome 50.0.2661.102)

Comment: I use IE 11.0.9600.18015IS

Comment: Working in IE 11.0.9600.18314 https://plnkr.co/Zz4vxq9Qe3KzZSggLMf6. jQuery library 2.2.0 used here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.paste').on('paste',function () {
            alert('something pasted');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is run very well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('paste','.paste', function () {
      alert('something pasted');
  });
});
```

code : https://jsfiddle.net/ChaHyukIm/zcrh3fz3/1/

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6397

I was working on my debugger with IE 8 screen. :_(

Thank you for your help.